# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, console

I am getting this cryptic message: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
I have googled and people think it has something to do with not properly dismissing a UITextField or Alert. I have one textfield in my app and I assure you I release it properly using resignFirstResponder, etc... 
I get this message when I am opening a MPMusicPickerController from a subview, does that make any difference. I really need to get this fixed because it is messing up my whole app!

Thanks,
Brad

Edit1:

```
    - (IBAction)openMediaPicker:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAny];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select songs to play";
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
    [mediaPicker release];
} 

// Media picker delegate methods
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.tr2 stop];
    [playstopButton setHidden:NO];
    [playstopButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Stop-Music-Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // We need to dismiss the picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    // Assign the selected item(s) to the music player and start playback.
    [self.musicPlayer stop];
    [self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
    [self.musicPlayer play];

}

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {
    // User did not select anything
    // We need to dismiss the picker
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: is it crashing your app?

Comment: @Daniel no its not crashing the app but it just doesn't perform a method I need it to most likely because of this problem.

Comment: perhaps show whats not working, we might be able to  identify your problem easier

Comment: I posted the problem in another stackoverflow question but I figured this was the actual problem. Anyway here is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199322/mpmusicplayercontrollernowplayingitemdidchangenotification-not-called

Comment: its gonna be hard to know what the problem is from just that snippet imo

Comment: should I post the showing of the mpmusicpicker and all the related methods?

Comment: the only thing that strikes me there, maybe check that the musicPlayer isnt nil ?

Comment: nope it isn't nil. Would you like me to post all my code for the music picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally:

1. You should not do any animations in `viewWillAppear` only in `viewDidAppear`. Only prepare your data, outlets etc. in `viewWillAppear`.
2. Also a very common case where `wait_fences` might arise is when you have an animated dialog (Like your `MPMediaPickerController`) that causes another animated view to appear (Like a custom modal `UIViewController`) or the like, in which case you need to "postpone" the presentation of the second viewcontroller like this:

   ```
       [self performSelector:@selector(showMyOtherViewController) 
                  withObject:nil 
                  afterDelay:0.1];
   ```

Also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/7194182.

**Edit**

A good way to "debug" conflicting animations is to simply set the animation to `NO` so in your code instead of

```
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Simply do:

```
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:NO];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

and check if the `wait_fences` error goes away and the correct behaviour (but without animation) is achieved. If this is the case you need some of the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`-magic.

**Edit:** Please note that you can do the following in iOS 5.0:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:NULL]
}
```

That means that first, the currently presented View Controller (e.g. a ModalViewController) is dismissed and when the animation is finished you can invoke another block. In this case show another `UIViewController`

Comment: What exactly is wait_fences? Does it make my app slower, less efficient?

Comment: I don't know what wait_fences exactly means, but I think it's thrown when animations and UI-drawing related errors or "collisions" occur. I don't think that it makes your App slower, but it suggests that there is a problem in your code, which you should obviously try to resolve.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that you are my hero, been trying to fix this issue for several days and the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that replacing clickedButtonAtIndex: with didDismissWithButtonIndex: when using  UIActionSheet or UIAlertView seems to make the error message go away.