# What exactly does the `wait_fences` error message mean

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've come accross the `wait_fences` error message [several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199628/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003/8791246#8791246).

I could not find any official documentation about itI would like to know in what circumstances this error message occurs and what exactly it means.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217371/problems-playing-ipod-in-app-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337183/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-on-loading-uialertview-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do your animations only when you have your view appeared. You should not try to manipulate the view before it actually appears. That means you should override `viewDidAppear` and not `viewWillAppear`.